# Preventing the function marking the input background unless its duplicated

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, background-color

Ok , so i got this 2 blocks of JS code down below ,
The first block evokes the function via input event listener ,
and the second block contains the function which gives same input values a same background color , the problem is that the function gives the background color to any indivitual number even if its not sharing a duplicated value, id like to make it mark the background only on a duplicated value input and havent figured it out , thanks for the help.

Type 1 in other input to check the function.

HTML:

```
    <input type="number" id="InputOf-Col0-Row0" value = 1>
    <input type="number" id="InputOf-Col0-Row1">
    <input type="number" id="InputOf-Col0-Row2">
    <input type="number" id="InputOf-Col0-Row3">
```

JS:

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
let a = document.getElementById(`InputOf-Col${0}-Row${i}`)
a.addEventListener('input', doThing);

}


function doThing(){

    for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
      let SelectInputs = document.getElementById(`InputOf-Col${0}-Row${i}`);
      let SelectedInputsValues = SelectInputs.value
      if(parseInt(this.value) == SelectedInputsValues ) {
       SelectInputs.style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
       setTimeout(()=> {  
         SelectInputs.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
       }, 1000);
       //  break;
       
  
  }
  
  
   }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

little bit of change may work..

```
function doThing(){

        for(let i=0; i<4; i++){
          let SelectInputs = document.getElementById(`InputOf-Col${0}-Row${i}`);
          let SelectedInputsValues = SelectInputs.value
          if(parseInt(this.value) == SelectedInputsValues && this.id != SelectInputs.id) {
           SelectInputs.style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
           this.style.backgroundColor= 'lime';
           setTimeout(()=> {  
             SelectInputs.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
             this.style.backgroundColor= 'transparent';
           }, 1000);
           //  break;
           
      
      }
```

Comment: @matan2288 . If the above answer was helpful, an upvote will make my day. :)